# Navigate to class in project view - intelij

Tags: intellij-idea

I upgraded my IDE to the new version 2019.3
in the previous version I have the ability to navigate in the project view to the class that I am currently working on.
today this is not displayed
how can I restore it?
[image]

this is the old menu, I want to add the icon that is marked in purple
[image: - inteli]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you have the option `Always Select Opened File` enabled under the cog menu? When this is enabled the file currently open in the editor is selected automatically in the project view. This makes the "locate" action unnecessary and it is hidden.